# Error on Auth section in AWS SAM template

Tags: aws-sam

To enable AWS_IAM auth and CORS, I made my sam template as follows.

However, I got an error saying

> Failed to create the changeset: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state Status: FAILED. Reason: Transform AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 failed with: Invalid Serverless Application Specification document. Number of errors found: 1. Resource with id [ListFunction] is invalid. Event with id [ListFunctionCors] is invalid. **Unable to set Authorizer [NONE] on API method [options] for path [/list] because the related API does not define any Authorizers.**

What is wrong here?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  ListApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: AWS_IAM
      Cors:
        AllowMethods: "'*'"
        AllowHeaders: "'*'"
        AllowOrigin: "'*'"
  ListFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: app_src/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      Events:
        ListFunction:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref ListApi
            Path: /list
            Method: GET
        ListFunctionCors:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref ListApi
            Path: /list
            Method: OPTIONS
            Auth:
              Authorizer: 'NONE'
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found to this issue is more of a workaround.
It appears that the source of the error message you get is [here](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/release/v1.13.0/samtranslator/model/eventsources/push.py#L544-L564)

From my understanding, 3 cases are not allowed when you select to have a method authorizer other than `AWS_IAM`:
1. Having no authorizers defined
2. Selecting an authorizer other than `NONE` which does not exist in the defined authorizers
3. Selecting `NONE` as an authorizer without setting a default Authorizer.

The cases above do not handle the case of the `AWS_IAM` authorizer. It's the only type of authorizer which is only set as the `DefaultAuthorizer` without having to list it in the Authorizers dictionary.

So the workaround here would be to define a dummy custom authorizer and never use it.

In your case, this could be done like this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  ListApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: AWS_IAM
        Authorizers:
          Dummy:
            FunctionArn: !GetAtt ListFunction.Arn
      Cors:
        AllowMethods: "'*'"
        AllowHeaders: "'*'"
        AllowOrigin: "'*'"
  ListFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: app_src/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      Events:
        ListFunction:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref ListApi
            Path: /list
            Method: GET
        ListFunctionCors:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref ListApi
            Path: /list
            Method: OPTIONS
            Auth:
              Authorizer: 'NONE'
```

I added a custom lambda authorizer in your API, `Dummy`, which is never used. I used the arn of your already defined lambda, but you could create a placeholder lambda to use instead.

Bottomline: The only way you can currently use `Authorizer: 'NONE'` in SAM when using only `DefaultAuthorizer: AWS_IAM` is to add any other authorizer to your API.

Note: The `null` value for the Authorizer was proposed in the initial GitHub issue, but in the implementation they went for `NONE` value, as it is described in the documetation.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this same problem, and figured it out. Per https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/781, that function event should be:

```
ListFunctionCors:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref ListApi
            Path: /list
            Method: OPTIONS
            Auth:
              Authorizer: null
```

It's `Authorizer: null`, not `Authorizer: 'NONE'`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Aw, fudge. While this removes the error, it seems not to have the intended override effect.

Comment: Does not remove the Authorizer for the given path.